# Sails.js 0.10 sockets not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

With the out of date docs on sails' sockets implementation i'm struggling to get the basic 'connect' message. Here's my node.js server side code:

```
sails.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
            sails.log.info('socket connected');

            //create room and broadcast a welcome message
            socket.emit('user joined', {'message': 'Welcome to ' + roomName});
            socket.join(roomName);
            socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('user joined', {'message': 'Welcome to ' + roomName});
        });
```

and my client side:

```
         var sock = io.connect('http://localhost:8888');
        sock.on('connection', function(socket){
            console.log('conected to server');
        });
        sock.on('user joined', function (json) {
            console.log('socket: ' + json);
        });
```

I do get the OK message from sails itself on start up but can't seem to get a connection of my own:

`` sails.io.js:200  `io.socket` connected successfully.
 (for help, see: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/BrowserSDK/BrowserSDK.html) ``

I tried using socket.io v1 and got the same weird situation. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On server `config/sockets.js`

```
module.exports.sockets = {
  onConnect: function(session, socket) {
    sails.log.verbose('>>>    socket user connected');
    sails.sockets.blast('eventName', dataToBlast);
  },
};
```

Documentation http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/anatomy/myApp/config/sockets.js.html

On client

```
io.socket.on('eventName', function(dataToBlast) {
   // process dataToBlast
});
```

Documentation http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js/io.socket.on.html

Be aware that socket needs to be subscribed to `eventName`. To subscribe you need to make controller `SubscribeController.js` and make request to it's action via socket.

```
var SubscribeController = {
  sub: function(req, res) {
     ModelName.subscribe(
         req.socket, 
         [] /*records to subscribe to or empty array to subscribe to all */, 
         ['eventName'] /* array of strings eventNames */
     );
  },
};
```

For debugging client you can connect to `firehose` which will give your client all messages from sails server

```
io.socket.get('/firehose');
io.socket.on('firehose', function newMessageFromSails(message) {
                typeof console !== 'undefined' &&
                    console.log('New message published from Sails ::\n', message);
            });
```

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. i realized i had a structural misunderstanding of sockets. i thought i could create a new socket connection in the client. apparently you only get one socket connection. Sails.js references a file called app.js which shows how it connects to sails and then puts it on the window for access throughout the rest of the app.